# Can the crimes of mercenary groups such as Wagner be attributed to the countries using them?

Tags: international-relations, international-law

Can the crimes of mercenary groups such as Wagner be attributed to the countries using them? The U.S. also have the infamous Blackwater group, so I am wondering if there exist laws that holds the country using those groups accountable in certain situations. I am thinking that the countries are only held accountable if the orders are made by the country, but often the decisions are made by the leaders of those groups, so I am thinking there's no framework to hold them accountable for just using them.

Comment: It's important to note that in the case of Wagner, they are almost part of the Russian army, getting supplies, ammunition and probably also salaries from them. They are manned part of the front and followed aims given by the Russian MoD. That is almost like mercenaries in name only or a hidden regular army. Of course there were differences, as for example seen currently.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Countries as a whole might be "held accountable" for warcrimes in the court of public opinon, but not in international courts. International courts and warcrime tribunals indict individual people, not whole countries. Those people can be those who personally committed warcrimes, or leaders on any level of the chain of command who ordered warcrimes to be committed.

When a leader is accused of ordering warcrimes, then the exact nature of how they were related to the people who executed their orders should not matter.

Countries might also be held accountable for their actions through UN resolutions. For example resolution [S/RES/687(1991)](https://undocs.org/Home/Mobile?FinalSymbol=S%2FRES%2F687(1991)&Language=E&DeviceType=Desktop&LangRequested=False) made Iraq responsible for warcrimes committed during the second Gulf war and demanded them to pay reparations. But the UN is a political organisation, not a court of law. Countries are not obligated to follow any ruleset when they decide how to vote on a UN resolution. So whether or not a UN delegation holds a country responsible for actions of their PMCs (or at all) is a decision they make based on their own political interests.

Comment: Actually, countries can be found liable for reparations which is a stronger form of accountability than mere public opinion.

Comment: @jwdonahue Reparations are usually part of a bilateral peace treaty, not imposed by a 3rd party. The height of reparations depends on how much the losing side is able and willing to pay for peace, not what they did or didn't do during the war.

Comment: @Philipp But OP didn't specify whether a third party (i.e. the ICC etc.) should be involved, or if this was something which must be considered as part of any peace process. OTOH the caption specifically refers to "crimes"...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Nothing "must" be considered as part of a peace process. What is and isn't considered is up to the negotiating parties.

Comment: @Philipp OK, I'll rephrase that: "should be considered as part of any peace process, if it is outside the jurisdiction of all third parties such as the ICC".

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd What "should" be considered depends on what can lead to a successful result of the negotiations. You are acting as if there was some obligatory rulebook for international relationships that must be followed. There is not. International politics is anarchy.

Comment: No I am /not/. I am trying to find a sequence of words that keeps you happy. Would "might be considered" do? The point I'm trying to make is that even if it's outside the remit of the ICC etc. (where individuals are prosecuted) it might still be relevant to negotiations where a /state/ might be found culpable.

Comment: Russia, however, has been found accountable for MH17.

Comment: @Stančikas Did that have any tangible consequences for Russia as a country, though?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I added another paragraph explaining how a country might or might not be held accountable in the United Nations.

Comment: @Philipp seems reasonable. Again, though- and note that I'm not necessarily disagreeing with you- OP specifically referred to "crimes of mercenary groups" which might have the effect of ruling out anything which isn't explicitly styled a court e.g. the UNSC.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**. A State is responsible for all acts committed by its organs and other persons or entities empowered to act on its behalf, even if such organs or persons exceed their authority or contravene instructions [(source)](https://www.geneva-academy.ch/joomlatools-files/docman-files/Academy%20Briefing%2013.pdf), see there page 26 section A.

I think that mercenaries officially hired by a State should be "empowered to act on its behalf". V. Putin said the mercenaries had been “[fully funded](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/jul/01/putin-claim-that-russia-funds-wagner-group-may-make-it-easier-to-try-him-for-war-crimes)” by Russian authorities.

Comment: I'd state that based on source that you linked, Russia would be responsible for Wagner group, as long as Wagner group does not become an "armed non-state actor". Let's say last weekend we were on brink of such transition...

Answer (score 0):

Russian nationals working for Wagner in Ukraine (and US nationals working for Blackwater in an armed conflict that the US is involved in) do not meet the definition of "mercenary" prevailing in international law.  This definition excludes everyone who is a national of a party to the conflict.

For example, the 1989 [International Convention against the Recruitment, Use, Financing and Training of Mercenaries](https://www.ohchr.org/en/instruments-mechanisms/instruments/international-convention-against-recruitment-use-financing-and) has this definition with respect to "armed conflict":

> A mercenary is any person who:
>
> a. Is specially recruited locally or abroad in order to fight in an armed conflict;
>
> b. Is motivated to take part in the hostilities essentially by the desire for private gain and, in fact, is promised, by or on behalf of a party to the conflict, material compensation substantially in excess of that promised or paid to combatants of similar rank and functions in the armed forces of that party;
>
> c. Is neither a national of a party to the conflict nor a resident of territory controlled by a party to the conflict;
>
> d. Is not a member of the armed forces of a party to the conflict; and
>
> e. Has not been sent by a State which is not a party to the conflict on official duty as a member of its armed forces.

Because all of these elements must be met for any person to meet the definition of "mercenary," anyone who possesses either Russian or Ukrainian nationality cannot be a mercenary in an armed conflict between Russia and Ukraine.

Nationals of other countries may be mercenaries (provided that they also meet the other elements of the definition).

There is no definition of "mercenary groups" as far as I'm aware.  Indeed, war crimes are typically prosecuted against individuals, not states or companies.  Could Russia be forced to pay reparations to Ukraine for crimes committed by Wagner personnel?  Yes.  Reparations  are typically a matter of diplomacy.  Criminal prosecution of crimes committed by Wagner Group personnel would be directed against the people who committed the crimes, including those who gave the orders.

Comment: I also posted as similar answer before, being convinced in this. However there is another definition of the mercenary in the same document that only states "neither a national nor a resident of the State against which such an act is directed" as the nationality-related restriction. This needs to be at least more in depth analyzed.

Comment: @Stančikas that definition applies to "any other situation" than armed conflict.